# XText cross referencing

Tags: eclipse, parsing, dsl, xtext

I have written following grammar

```
Model:
package = PackageDec?
greetings+=Greeting*
usage+=Usage* ;

PackageDec:
   'package' name=QualifiedName ;

Greeting:
'greet' name=ID '{' ops += Operation* '}' ;

Operation:
'op' name=ID ('(' ')' '{' '}')? ;

QualifiedName:
ID ('.' ID)*;

Usage: 
   'use';
```

With above i can write following script.

```
package p1.p2
  greet G1 {op f1 op f2 }
```

Now i need to write something like this:

```
  package p1.p2
  greet G1 {op f1 op f2 op f3}
  use p1.p2.G1.f1
  use p1.p2.G1
  use p1.p2.G1.f3
```

To support that i changed Usage RULE like this

```
Usage:
'use' head=[Greet|QualifiedName] =>('.' tail=[Operation])?
```

However when i generate xtext artifacts it is complaining about multiple alternatives.

Please let me know how to write correct grammar rule for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `QualifiedName` consumes dots (`.`). Adding `('.' ...)?` makes two alternatives. Consider input

```
a.b.c
```

This could be parsed as

- `head="a"` `tail = "b.c"`
- `head="a.b"` `tail = "c"`

If I understand your intention of using predicate `=>` right, than you just have to replace

```
head=[Greet|QualifiedName]
```

with

```
head=[Greet]
```

In this case however you will not be able to parse references with dots.

As a solution I would recommend to substitute your dot with some other character. For example with colon:

```
Usage:
'use' head=[Greet|QualifiedName] (':' tail=[Operation])?
```